# Is this cast okay?

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling, conventions

I have an EventHandler that I set as an [event filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#addEventFilter-javafx.event.EventType-javafx.event.EventHandler-) on TextFields. When I write the class, I get the source TextField by calling [getSource()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html?is-external=true#getSource--) on the event and casting it to a TextField.

The code for the EventHandler:

```
public class NumberFilter implements EventHandler<KeyEvent> {

    public final int maxLength;
    public NumberFilter(int maxLength) {
        this.maxLength = maxLength;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        TextField textField = (TextField) event.getSource(); //<-- is this cast okay?

        //consume event if there is too much text or the input isn't a number.
        if (textField.getText().length() >= maxLength || !event.getCharacter().matches("[0-9]")) {
            event.consume();
        }
    }
}
```

Is this cast okay by standard java conventions? How can I write the class so that it can't be used anywhere except as an event filter for a TextField?

Comment: You can write your custom TextField which would use anonymous class or private class with your filter.

Comment: @MGorgon I originally had the EventHandler as an anonymous class, but then I decided I wanted to use it elsewhere, and made it into a class of its own.

Comment: Just don't do it like this at all. (For one thing, if the user pastes text by bringing up a context menu with the mouse, it completely bypasses all your checks anyway.) Use a `TextFormatter` on the text field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Andy Turner's answer provides a robust general approach to allowing event handlers to be added to only one type of `Node`. However, for the specific case of vetoing changes to the text in a `TextField` (or other text input control), the approach of using key event handlers is not a good one for the following reasons:

1. The user can bring up a context menu with the mouse and paste text in. This doesn't involve any key presses at all, so your handler won't be invoked.
2. You have no control over which type of key events the text field uses internally. Are you registering this filter with `KEY_PRESSED`, `KEY_RELEASED`, or `KEY_TYPED` events? Are you sure the events used internally by the text field will remain the same from one JavaFX release to the next?
3. You will likely inadvertently veto keyboard shortcuts such as Ctrl-C (for copy) or Ctrl-V (for paste), and similar. (If you don't veto shortcuts for "paste", you allow another loophole for the user to paste invalid text...). Again, it's possible a future release of JavaFX may introduce additional shortcuts, which it's virtually impossible to proof your functionality against.

For completeness, the preferred approach for this particular use case is as follows:

Use a [`TextFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html), which is the supported mechanism for vetoing or modifying text entry to a text input control (as well as providing mechanisms to format or parse text in the control). You can make this reusable by implementing the filter in a standalone class:

```
public class NumberFilter implements UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> {

    private final Pattern pattern ;

    public NumberFilter(int maxLength) {
        pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{0,"+maxLength+"}");
    }

    @Override
    public TextFormatter.Change apply(TextFormatter.Change c) {
        String newText = c.getControlNewText() ;
        if (pattern.matcher(newText).matches()) {
            return  c ;
        } else {
            return null ;
        }
    }
}
```

And now you can do

```
TextField textField = new TextField();
textField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<String>(new NumberFilter(5)));
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to expand on my comment on [@MaxPower's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43879793/3788176):

Don't use inheritance to do something which you can more cleanly do with composition.

I think that @James_D's approach is better in this case; but if in general you want an `EventHandler` which can only be added to a certain type of field, enforce this through your API:

```
public class NumberFilter implements EventHandler<KeyEvent> {
  public static void addTo(int maxLength, TextField textField) {
    textField.addEventHandler(new NumberFilter(maxLength));  
  }

  private NumberFilter(int maxLength) {
    // Private ctor means that you can't just create one of these
    // however you like: you have to create it via the addTo method.
  }

  // Now casting in the handle() method is safe.
}
```

In this way, the only means of creating the `NumberFilter` is via the `addTo` method; and that requires that you're adding it to a `TextField`.

Answer (score 1):

Casts are a way of you telling the compiler that you know more then it does.

If you know that every time this piece of code gets called it will be from a TextField than it is okay.  Otherwise, I would do

```
try {
 TextField textField = (TextField) event.getSource();
 //Do Stuff
}
catch(ClassCastException e) {
//handle the error

}
```

or if you want a little more type safety

```
if(event.getSource() instanceof TextField) {
  TextField textField = (TextField) event.getSource();
}
```

Or better yet

```
public class MyTextField extends TextField implements EventHandler<KeyEvent> {

}
```

then place use this instead of TextField and add your method, then it's type safe.

Comment: "Or better yet" Yuk, no. Don't use inheritance for this, just only add the `EventHandler` which does the cast to a `TextField`.

Comment: Why not?, he wants an event handler that only accepts text fields, and in this case he does not have to reimplement the handler for every text field.

Comment: Why not? Because a `TextField` *isn't* an `EventHandler`, it might *have* an `EventHandler`.

Comment: You certainly should not use the try-catch if you know it is possible that the cast will fail. Use the instanceof test. But as I commented below the question, just don't use an event handler for this functionality in the first place.

Comment: Re-reading my first comment, even I wonder what I was smoking at the time. My brain seems to have filtered out words I meant to type. I meant to say: only add the `EventHandler` to `TextField`s, not any other type of `Node`.

Comment: * Do not use a try { } catch (ClassCastException e)  {} - ever -. Instead use instanceof
* Do not extend TextField if not strictly necessary, use a event handler that blocks event.